# Default values of new fields for existing entries

Tags: entries-field, plugin-seomatic

I added a new SEOmatic field to a section that has around 500 entries. As for any other new fields that you add to a section, the default values are only applied on the entries if you open and save every single one of them once. Shouldn't there be a solution form crafts side? Something like "apply on all existing entries"? Or is there any comfortable solution for that already existing?

... I am thinking about adding a feature request since I was struggling with this several times already. What do you guys think?

Found some other similar questions, but no really easy and satisfying solutions:

[Can I add an enabled-by-default lightswitch field to existing entries?](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/11269/can-i-add-an-enabled-by-default-lightswitch-field-to-existing-entries)